# Sorting a list with two different types in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that looks like this. [0,0,0,0,0,'entrya',5, 'entryb', 10, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entry', 1, 'entryd', 30, ...., 0,0,0,0,0,0]

and so on, I think the idea is clear. My Problem now is that I want to sort this whole list after the numbers associated to the string. So that the result look like this. ['entry', 1, 'entrya', 5, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entryb', 10, 'entryd', 30,.... 0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0] (or the other way round, what would even be better.)

My problem clearly is that the adjacent entries have to keep together and dictionaries aren't allowed for this excercise.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: create tuples from your list, then sort the tuples, then flatten the list. But there's no association at the start & end, only 0.0 ...

Comment: why `'entrya',5` is missed from the result?

Comment: oops forgot entry a. Edited

Comment: how can i create tuples from the list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand how your original list is constructed. If we call it `x` and every even entry (0, 2, ...) is a string and every odd entry (1, 3, ...) is a number associated with the preceding string you could turn it into a list of tuples as follows:

```
y = zip(x[0::2], x[1::2])
```

The list of tuples y can then be sorted:

```
y.sort(key=lambda t: t[1])
```

which would yield:

```
[(0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 (0, 0),
 ('entry', 1),
 ('entrya', 5),
 ('anotherentry', 7),
 ('entryb', 10),
 ('entryd', 30)]
```

Does this help?

EDIT:

To flatten it into a list again:

```
z = [entry for tup in y for entry in tup]
```

Comment: There's an odd number of zeros at the beginning, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @AChampion I was thinking one might be missing. If the list is actually a list of pairs then it has a structure which makes sense. If it's just an arbitrary number of zeros which doesn't really carry any information then I'd suggest finding another representation of the data in the first place.

Comment: no it worked just fine, the odd number of zeroes have been my fault, sorry.  It should be an even amount of zeroes

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to zip element in your list into tuple first like this:

```
[('null', 0), ('null', 0), ('null', 0), ('entrya', 5), ('entryb', 10), ('anotherentry', 7), ...]
```

Afterward, you can sort the element by the second element.

```
ls = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'entrya', 5, 'entryb', 10, 'anotherentry', 7, 
     'entry', 1, 'entryd', 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

ls_zip_elem = []
for x1, x2 in zip(ls, ls[1:]):
    if x1 == 0:
        ls_zip_elem.append(('null', x1))
    elif not str(x1).isdigit():
        ls_zip_elem.append((x1, x2))
    else:
        pass
ls_zip_elem_sorted = sorted(ls_zip_elem, key=lambda x: x[1]) # sorted

# put the list back
ls_sorted = []
for x1, x2 in ls_zip_elem_sorted:
    if x1 == 'null':
        ls_sorted.append(x2)
    else:
        ls_sorted.extend([x1, x2])

# output
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'entry', 1, 'entrya', 5, 'anotherentry', 7, 
# 'entryb', 10, 'entryd', 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very weird dataset, but assuming you really do need this then:
If you remove the `0`s at the beginning and the end then it is fairly easy to sort:

```
>>> l = ['entrya', 5, 'entryb', 10, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entry', 1, 'entryd', 30]
>>> [b for a in sorted(zip(*[iter(l)]*2), key=lambda x: x[1]) for b in a]
['entry', 1, 'entrya', 5, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entryb', 10, 'entryd', 30
```

So assuming you don't have `0` as a value to your other `entries`, then you can deal with this as 2 cases, sort everything not zero in pairs and then add back all the zeros.

```
>>> l = [0,0,0,0,0,'entrya',5, 'entryb', 10, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entry', 1, 'entryd', 30, 0,0,0,0,0]
>>> pairs = [b for a in sorted(zip(*[iter(filter(lambda x: x!=0, l))]*2), key=lambda x: x[1]) for b in a]
>>> zeros = list(filter(lambda x: x == 0, l))
>>> pairs + zeros
['entry', 1, 'entrya', 5, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entryb', 10, 'entryd', 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` from `functools` module, `add` from `operator`, `zip` and `sorted()` to have your desired output.

NB:

In this solution:

- You'll need to parse your input list and seperate the zeros from it.
- Then, create a pairs from the data, without zeros in it, based on the second element
- Finally concatenate step2 with a list of the zeros of step1

This is an example:

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

data =  [0,0,0,0,0,'entrya',5, 'entryb', 10, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entry', 1, 'entryd', 30, 0,0,0,0,0,0]
non_zeros, zeros = [k for k in data if k is not 0], [0]*data.count(0)
pairs = [[k,v] for k,v in zip(non_zeros[::2], non_zeros[1::2])]

final =  reduce(add, sorted(pairs, key= lambda x: x[1])) + zeros
print(final)
```

Output:

```
['entry', 1, 'entrya', 5, 'anotherentry', 7, 'entryb', 10, 'entryd', 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```